# Como salir del DIV en cada mensaje

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un problemilla y no logro dar con la solución

En el siguiente código genero con cada click al botón un DIV en el que pongo el nombre del usuario y el comentaroi que hace poniéndole un borde.

El problema que tengo, es que si se vuelve hacer otro comentario, me lo mete en el mismo DIV del comentario anterior en el mismo borde.

Lo que me gustaría, es que generase una nueva caja con su borde por cada comentario separando uno del otro

Alguien me puede ayudar ?

```
function commentBox()
{
    var txtNombre = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var txtComentario = document.getElementById('comment').value;

    if(txtNombre == "" || txtComentario == "")
    {
        alert("Porfavor introduce la informacion requerida!");
    }
    else
    {
        var etiquetaDIV = document.createElement('div');
        var etiquetaH5 = document.createElement('h5');
        etiquetaH5.style.paddingLeft = '20px';
        etiquetaH5.style.paddingTop = '10px';
        var etiquetaP = document.createElement('p');
        etiquetaP.style.paddingLeft = '20px';
        var linea = document.createElement('hr');
        var texto_nombre = document.createTextNode(txtNombre);
        var texto_mensaje = document.createTextNode(txtComentario);

        etiquetaH5.appendChild(texto_nombre);
        etiquetaP.appendChild(texto_mensaje);
        linea.style.border = '1px solid #999';

        etiquetaDIV.appendChild(etiquetaH5);
        etiquetaDIV.appendChild(linea);
        etiquetaDIV.appendChild(etiquetaP);
        etiquetaDIV.setAttribute('class', 'pane');

        document.getElementById('result').appendChild(etiquetaDIV);
        document.getElementById('result').style.border = '1px solid #555';
        document.getElementById('result').style.borderRadius = '22px';

        document.getElementById('name').value="";
        document.getElementById('comment').value="";
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código HTML

```
<section id="app" class="principal">
    <div class="container-fluid pane">
        <div class="fila row">
            <div class="col-0 col-md-3">

            </div>
           <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="">
                    <h3 id="txtComenta">

                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div id="result">
  
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-0 col-md-3">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fila row">
            <div class="col-0 col-md-4">

            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="nombre">

                        </label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text"  id="name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="labelComenta">

                        </label>
                        <textarea id="comment" class="form-control">

                        </textarea>
                    </div>
                    <button id="btnEnviar" type="button" class="botones" style="width: 196px; height: 30px; margin-top: 10px;" onclick="commentBox();">
                    
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-0 col-md-4">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: tu codigo no esta completo, agrega tu html, donde llamas a al evento 'click'?

Comment: @infinit3Loop__, gracias por la respuesta, pero no entiendo lo que me dices. He añadido el código completo de la función, había subido solo un estracto, ahora he añadido la función completa que responde al evento del botón

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solo tienes crear un contenedor que envuelva a cada comentario nuevo, a ese contenedor sera al que le apliques los bordes, despues insertas ese contenedor en el div 'result'

```js
let name_ = document.getElementById('name')
let comment = document.getElementById('comment')
let result = document.getElementById('result')

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  let container = document.createElement('div') // por cada nuevo nombre/comentario le creamos un contenedor, este sera el que tenga los bordes
  container.style.border = '1px solid #555';
  container.style.borderRadius = '22px';
  let etiquetaDIV = document.createElement('div');
  let etiquetaH5 = document.createElement('h5');
  etiquetaH5.style.paddingLeft = '20px';
  etiquetaH5.style.paddingTop = '10px';
  let etiquetaP = document.createElement('p');
  etiquetaP.style.paddingLeft = '20px';
  let linea = document.createElement('hr');
  let texto_nombre = document.createTextNode(name_.value);
  let texto_mensaje = document.createTextNode(comment.value);
  
  etiquetaH5.appendChild(texto_nombre);
  etiquetaP.appendChild(texto_mensaje);
  linea.style.border = '1px solid #999';
  
  etiquetaDIV.appendChild(etiquetaH5);
  etiquetaDIV.appendChild(linea);
  etiquetaDIV.appendChild(etiquetaP);
  etiquetaDIV.setAttribute('class', 'pane');
  
  container.appendChild(etiquetaDIV) // agregamos el contenido al contenedor
  result.appendChild(container); // agregamos el contenedor al div 'result'
  name_.value="";
  comment.value="";
})
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="result"></div>
  <input type="text" id="name">
  <input type="text" id="comment">
  <button id="button">add</button>
  <script src="scripts2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me ha funcionado. Ahora tengo que ponerme a estudiar los cambios. Lo dicho, Muchísimas gracias

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás creando sólo un DIV (`etiquetaDIV`) y añadiendo todo el contenido del comentario a ese mismo DIV. Por eso, los comentarios se están agregando uno tras otro como si fueran parte del mismo contenido.

Una solución sería crear un nuevo DIV para cada comentario que el usuario añade, y luego agregar ese DIV al `div` existente que contiene todos los comentarios. Aquí te muestro cómo hacerlo:

```
var newCommentDiv = document.createElement('div');
newCommentDiv.setAttribute('class', 'comment');

var etiquetaH5 = document.createElement('h5');
etiquetaH5.style.paddingLeft = '20px';
etiquetaH5.style.paddingTop = '10px';
var etiquetaP = document.createElement('p');
etiquetaP.style.paddingLeft = '20px';
var linea = document.createElement('hr');

var texto_nombre = document.createTextNode(txtNombre);
var texto_mensaje = document.createTextNode(txtComentario);

etiquetaH5.appendChild(texto_nombre);
etiquetaP.appendChild(texto_mensaje);

linea.style.border = '1px solid #999';

newCommentDiv.appendChild(etiquetaH5);
newCommentDiv.appendChild(linea);
newCommentDiv.appendChild(etiquetaP);

// Agregamos el nuevo comentario al div de todos los comentarios
var allCommentsDiv = document.getElementById('result');
allCommentsDiv.appendChild(newCommentDiv);

// Agregamos un margen entre cada comentario
allCommentsDiv.style.marginTop = "10px";
allCommentsDiv.style.marginBottom = "10px";
allCommentsDiv.style.paddingTop = "10px";

// Estilizamos el borde
allCommentsDiv.style.border = '1px solid #555';
allCommentsDiv.style.borderRadius = '22px';

document.getElementById('name').value = "";
document.getElementById('comment').value = "";
```

Comment: Relacionado -> https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido

Comment: Hola @Xedrian, gracias por tu respuesta, he copiado tu código y sustituido con él el mío, y me sigue sucediendo lo mismo.